# Can't access nodejs from external ip in digital ocean

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, digital-ocean

i want to deploy an vue application with express backend both on one virtual machine on digital ocean . I have successfully deploy vue application and i am able to access it with external ip but express backend is not working i started the server with pm2 but vue application which is hosted and working properly is not able to connect to express bakcend also i am not able to access it through external ip like this :3000

i have enabled port 3000 on firewall my mongo db is working and server is properly doing there stuff

Comment: Can you use a tool like postman to request your express backend and see what the response or error is?

Comment: Need more info than this to troubleshoot. Do you have a mongo server running? what port is it running on if it is and how is it wired up to expxress. Is express running on port 3000 or the server serving vue or are you trying to run both with pm2 on the same port? Are you getting any errors when you open dev tools on your browser?